# Spring & Java - Serialize hierarchical tree structure

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm working on adapting the unlimited nested [angular-ui-tree](http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/tree.html) module to use server side serialization and persistence.

Right now, I have the GET functionality working and an existing nested tree structure rendering.  The part I'm striking out, however, deals with the create and update operations (POST and PUT).

Given that JSON structure on the side of that page and where each node is a JSON representative of the domain model below, how can I save and update the data?

```
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "category_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column
  private String category;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Category parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();

  //getters, setters

}
```

I have an existing controller set up here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/category", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<Category> createCategory(@RequestBody Category category){

}
```

but it only works for single category objects where the incoming JSON follows the representation of the `Category` properties.  My alternative is to have the entire JSON structure sent to this controller on a create/update operation and update both the persistence as well as the tree structure.

I'm stuck on how to recieve this data in the first place.  Are there any existing libraries or serializers that can be adapted to this use case?